# Extracting URL from behind the certificate webpage using python Beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.8

I need to access behind a certificate data for which I have a PEM file.
Following is the image. The left side in blue XML points to the url you can see on the right starting as mis.ercot.com/misdownload. I need to extract the two urls. When I right click on the webpage and chose source, those URLs are not displayed as probably they are behind the certificate.

Comment: It's impossible to debug this without the cert, hence the downvote, I guess. How did you get it?

Comment: _When I right click on the webpage and chose source, those URLs are not displayed as probably they are behind the certificate._  How is this possible? The image clearly shows the URLs in the table `reportTable`

Comment: Does the `BeautifulSoup` object `XMLurls` contain the URLs?

Comment: That's completely waste of time for people here! This site is behind `Incapsula` (Impreva), Simply calling `curl -Lc - ercot.com` will confirm that, You even didn't posted your response code and I understood well why you didn't shared the SSL certificated, That's completely SSL pinning and that thing is out of the scope here.

Comment: Secondly, you will not be able to call that site using Native HTTP request unless you are good enough to reverse engineering the `Reese84` cookie.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη the response code would be highly useful in determining if the OP has authenticated to the site.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex OP will never ever be authenticated to the site by any meaning, Impreva never issue a private certificate to anyone as the Cipher is completely private. Simply save [that](https://bpa.st/PMDJE) as `.pem` and call the site!

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Ercot does issue private certificates to users that need to access restricted resources.  This information is mentioned [here](https://www.ercot.com/mktrules/guides/data_transport/security) and [here](https://www.ercot.com/static-assets/data/help/v2/Content/Topics/MIS/loginhelp.htm)

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex That's correct but again, The certificate which he's trying to use is disabled due to SSL pinning which means he's not the owner of it, [check-that](https://bpa.st/3EHM2)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη the user didn't provide their `cert.pem` so how do you know that the user doesn't have one issued by Ercot?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex open the URL, check the redirection. BTW, the ID is unique one issued per user, Each ID redirect to it's resource based on the cert used.

Comment: My guess is that the OP might have a particular intermediate certificate, which, obviously, cannot be shared. Hence, I agree with you, @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, that this question is unanswerable as is. Also, the ecrot.com domain is even hard to reach without a VPN set to a US server. Anyhow, well researched, ahmed.

Comment: It is true that ercot.com uses IP address filtering based on geographic location.  It seems that the OP has a valid  certificate, because of the screenshoot in their question.  I cannot get to this page in the US without being warned that i don’t have a certificate.

Comment: I added some rough code on using `selenium` for your use case.  It's hard to test this without having my own certificate.  Let me know if the code works for you.

Comment: I haven't heard back from you in the extend chat session.  Did you try these `selenium` items that I suggested?  if so, what was the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED 05-08-2023

Concerning using `selenium` for your use case. You should be able to use `selenium`, but first you need to import your certificate into Chrome or another browser.

Here are the [directions](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-do-I-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome-) for doing this in Chrome.  Please note the name of the Profile where you installed this certificate.

Here is some rough code to use this profile with `selenium` and with the `chromedriver`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# add the path to user data
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google Chrome/User Data")

# add the profile here 
chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://mis.ercot.com')

# add the rest of the code needed to navigate to the page that you need.
```

### ORIGINAL POST 05-06-2023

***I previously deleted this answer, because it was mostly informational and was designed for troubleshooting your question.  I will likely delete this answer again after you update your question with the required information.***

Since deleting this answer *Baduker*, *αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη* and myself have highlighted several things in the comments, which are needed for anyone to assist you in solving your issue.

---

**First**, we need to know if the `cert.pem` file that you are using was issued to you or to someone within your organization by the *Electric Reliability Council of Texas*.

---

**Second**, if the certificate was issued by ERCOT we need to know what *HTTP status code* you are receiving when calling `connection.get(url)`

```
from requests import Session

url = "https://mis.ercot.com/secure/data-products/markets/settlements?id=NP9-148-SG"

connection = Session()
connection.cert = fr"B:\allCerts\cert.pem"
response = connection.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
###################################
# should return 200
###################################
```

---

**Third**, if the *HTTP status code* is *200* then we need to know if the **unfiltered** SOUP object contains the URLs that you need.

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mis.ercot.com/secure/data-products/markets/settlements?id=NP9-148-SG"

connection = Session()
connection.cert = fr"B:\allCerts\cert.pem"
response = connection.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
###################################
# are the URLs in this SOUP object?
###################################
```

---

**Fourth**, if the URLs are in the SOUP object then check the syntax of this line:

XMLurls = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml").find_all("a")[::2]

---

FYI I personally would extract the HREFs directly from this table, which is shown in the image attached to your question.

```
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'reportTable'})
for link in table.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "XML" in link.text:
        print(a['href'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to send the PEM file to chrome to provide the path to .cert file as there are multiple certs that I have, currently it opens a pop up when chrome starts and it tries to access mis.ercot

Comment: So when you added all the certs and added the profile containing these certs to selenium it didn’t log you in?  How do you normally login?  And what browser do you use?

Comment: I use chrome but there is a pop up to select from multiple certificates as ERCOT gives different certs for different activities. i.e mis.ercot.com has multiple functionalities and hence different certs.

Comment: Are the certs that you currently use embedded in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, when I installed the certs they go to the default trusted locations where other microsoft certs are

Comment: Ok.  So to determine if the certs are available in your selenium session I would open the main page www.ercot.com with driver.get. After that I would manually try to login with the button on the page.  If the certs are available you should be able to select them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253561/discussion-between-zanam-and-life-is-complex).

Answer (score -1):

You can read the `pem` file separately -

```
with open(fr"B:\allCerts\cert.pem", 'rb') as file:
    pem_data = file.read()
```

I have modified your code. You can try to pass the `cert` in the `.get` method itself -

```
response = connection.get(url, cert=pem_data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    XMLurls = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    href_urls = XMLurls.find_all("a", href=True)[::2]
    for link in XMLurls:
        url = link.get("href")
        print(url)
```